# bash loop all files in directory, then loop lines of each file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, newlines

I have

```
urls1.txt
urls2.txt
urls3.txt
```

And so on.

How can I loop all files in this directory then loop each line of these files?

Comment: What would you want to do to each line of each file? It's _very seldom_ necessary to read in lines from a file in a shell script. It's more common to process each file through `awk` or `sed` or some such tool.  See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716

Comment: This seems simple enough to do even notwithstanding the truth of @Kusalananda's comment.  What have you tried?  How did it not work as expected or intended?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as it is written you can do the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for file in /path/to/files/*.txt; do
    # This will loop through each .txt file in the directory
    # setting the full file path to $file
    # I recommend adding the .txt if you know all your files
    # will have that extension otherwise the following is fine:
    # for file in /path/to/files/*; do
    while read -r line; do
        # This will loop through each line of the current file
        # and set the full line to the $line variable
        command "$line"
    done < "$file"
done
```

Explanations are in comments within the code

Comment: IT doesnt work 
./test.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `while'
./test.sh: line 16: `    while read -r line; do'

Comment: @Bornvs.Me: sorry I forgot a `do` in the for loop, see if that fixes it.

Comment: It'll trim whitespace.